# could not open version file PG_VERSION postgresql pg upgrade

Tags: windows, postgresql, pg-upgrade

I need some help please, I am upgrading postgresql from v10 to v11 on Windows, but get the following error message: `could not open version file: C:/Program Files/PostgresSQL/11/data/PG_VERSION`.

Here are the steps taken:

1. Stopped both PostgresSQL v10 and PostgresSQL v11 services using

   ```
   services.msc
   ```
2. Set full access control/complete permissions for users for both v10 and v11.
3. Created 'postgres' user account with full admin rights.
4. Opened command-line and entered

   ```
   RUNAS /USER:postgres "CMD.EXE
   ```

   prompted to enter password for user postgres user.
5. New command-line window opens and cd to 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11'.
6. Entered the following:

```
pg_upgrade.exe --old-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/data" --new-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data" --old-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin" --new-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/bin" --check
```

On pressing enter I get the above mentioned error.

I am new to the whole process of using PostgreSQL.

Any thoughts on what is wrong?

Comment: 1. *How* are you upgrading PostgreSQL? What steps are you following? 2. *What command* generates that error? 3. What do the logs say?

Comment: Using `pg_upgrade` from v11 and ran the following ```pg_upgrade --old-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/data" --new-datadir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data" --old-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin" --new-bindir "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/bin" --check``` from `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11` from the cli

Comment: Storing the data directory into `c:\Program File` is a really bad idea. Regular users are not allowed to write there (for good reasons). It's a **really**, really bad choice of the EnterpriseDB installer to suggest that directory. `%ProgramData%` is  **much** better place to store that

Comment: Yes, but it's a local machine I use for development, only I have use this machine

Comment: I had this error because I had a copy paste error, and instead of passing a data dir I was passing a bin dir. Doesn't look like your problem, but maybe the data dir in you old distribution was renamed? Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had to grant \postgres modify access to both the old and the new datadirectory. That solved the problem for me while upgrading from 9.6 to 10

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by *not* running a cmd as postgres user.
Instead I made a passwsord file and set the env PGPASSFILE accordingly:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-pgpass.html

Apparently when running cmd as postgres user, it was some permissions that prohibited the PG_VERSION to be opened